# Php Displaying Blank Page With No Errors

Tags: php, mysqli

hi i am developing a website and i need to delete files from a server i currently have the following code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/Scripts/Functions.php");
top();
```

THis Seems To Be The Problem

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM 'Gallery' WHERE 'ID' = '20'";
if (!mysqli_query(connect(),$query))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error(connect()));
}
else
{
 $Result = mysqli_query(connect(),$query);
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result))
      {
          $file = get_local($row['Image_Location']);
          unlink($file);
          $query2 = "DELETE FROM Gallery WHERE ID='20'";
            if (mysqli_query(connect(),$query2))
            {
                header("Location: http://test.co.uk/Gallery/Edit/")
            }
            else
            {
                die('Error: ' . mysqli_error(connect()));
            }
      }
}


bottom();
?>
```

after going through the code i have worked out that it is an error with the if (!mysqli_query(connect(),$query)) section yet i i cant manage to work out whats wrong.

Comment: Enabling error_reporting in a script containing syntax errors is a bit late, as the settings call will never be executed either.

Comment: ini_set won't work if there is a fatal error. Either set display_errors somewhere else (i.e. php.ini) or watch error logs for the error message

Comment: please split your check if (!mysqli_query(connect(),$query)) to two separate checks 
1) if(!$res = connect())
2) if(!mysqli_query($res,$query))

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing a semi-colon on this line:

```
header("Location: http://www.littlesaintspreschool.co.uk/Gallery/Edit/")
```

Answer (score -1):

The first problem I spot is that you have your table surrounded by single quotes.
When referring to database elements, like,

- the database name
- the table name
- the field name

You must use backticks ` which is located to the left of the 1 key and above tab.

The second problem I see is that you are passing a function to mysqli_query.  Not knowing what the return value is for connect()... I can't exactly say that that is the problem.  Regardless, you should store your connection in a variable rather than a function.